# How to run a container on user-defined network in Go client for the Docker Engine API?

Tags: docker, go

I'm using [client.ContainerCreate](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v20.10.7+incompatible/client#Client.ContainerCreate) & [client.ContainerStart](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v20.10.7+incompatible/client#Client.ContainerStart) to run a container locally.

```
resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: repoName + "/" + imageName,
        Cmd:   []string{"--env", "stage=local", "--spec", testSpecFile},
        Tty:   false,
    }, &container.HostConfig{
        Binds: []string{
            "ui-automation:/automation",
        },
    }, nil, nil, "")
```

And following are the available networks,

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
1b17539cfd94   bridge    bridge    local
09dcddcdebad   host      host      local
2d5bb8da5fe6   kind      bridge    local
1d9dd2f2a18a   none      null      local
```

Now by default it's running on default `bridge` network. In CLI, if I wanted to attach my container to some other network, say `host`, I could do,

```
docker run --network host <image>
```

How to achieve the same using the above mentioned golang library ?

Comment: There is container network settings https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v20.10.7+incompatible/api/types/network#NetworkingConfig, have you check if?

Comment: Yes, I see that I need to provide endpoint configs for each connecting network(`EndpointsConfig map[string]*EndpointSettings`). Now the question is how to find existing `EndpointSettings`, the CLI equivalent of `docker network ls` ?

Comment: Hi @Philidor, I intend to use this method https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.NetworkConnect to connect my container to particular network. But I couldn't figure out how to retrieve one of the parameter, `networkID`.

Comment: I assume you can pass your network settings in this way https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/create_test.go#L12-L18 and after  that try use this exaample https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35752